# css animations border bottom not working in safari even though webkit keyframes declared

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations

i have a problem with safari not playing the border bottom animation for my navigation, it works on edge, firefox, chrome, just not safari im not quite sure what the problem is... here is my css:

```
        @keyframes pageon{
            0% {border-bottom: 0px solid #7b7b7b;}
            100% {border-bottom: 3px solid #7b7b7b;}
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes pageon{
            0% {-webkit-border-bottom: 0px solid #7b7b7b;}
            100% {-webkit-border-bottom: 3px solid #7b7b7b;}
        }

        .pageon{
            animation-name: pageon;
            animation-duration: 200ms;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            -webkit-animation-name: pageon;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 200ms;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }


        @keyframes pageoff{
            0% {border-bottom: 3px solid #7b7b7b;}
            100% {border-bottom: 0px solid #7b7b7b;}
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes pageoff{
            0% {-webkit-border-bottom: 3px solid #7b7b7b;}
            100% {-webkit-border-bottom: 0px solid #7b7b7b;}
        }

        .pageoff{
            animation-name: pageoff;
        animation-duration: 200ms;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            -webkit-animation-name: pageoff;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 200ms;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }
```

please help!! thank you:))

Comment: **[Refer this]**
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717076/css-animations-border-bottom-not-working-in-safari-even-though-webkit-keyframes#)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently is a bug on Safari, just add the initial border properties to your element `border-bottom: 0px solid #7b7b7b;` as you can see in the example.

```
.pageon{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #7b7b7b;
  animation: 500ms pageon infinite;
}
```

[Working example on Safari](https://jsfiddle.net/zwh8xy5a/2/)